# In space I am moving wrt to what?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, galilean-relativity

Let us suppose I am running on a street. When my eyes are open, I can see many things moving backward, and thus it gives me an idea that I am moving wrt those things. Not even this, even if I close my eyes during the run, I can really *feel* that I am moving.

Now assume that I reach a world where there is absolutely nothing except my own body, and my eyes are closed. I am still feeling that I am running.  The question is I am running wrt to what?

Even if I open my eyes I would  feel that I am still running, may be very fast. But visually I would not able to perceive my movement.

Does it mean that my movement in space is an illusion?

If not, then I am moving w.r.t what? There is absolutely nothing around me!

Comment: "The question is I am running wrt to what?" Great question. If there is absolutely nothing except your body, what are you running on? Furthermore, consider what you mean by you feel yourself running. Are you feeling the wind blow past? Is it simply the motion of your legs you feel (which can be done without moving forward)? If you are at a constant velocity, it feels no different than if you are standing still. Consider that Earth is moving around the Sun (approximately constant v) and the Sun moves around the galaxy. Do you feel these motions?

Comment: My point is, if you are in space with nothing around you and you don't feel an acceleration, then you are not moving. But if you see/sense lots of things passing by you all at the same speed, then it's safe to say that either you are the one moving or there is a vast migration of stellar objects going on that you missed the memo about (a "star trek", if you will)

Answer (score 2):

Galileo proposed that all inertial systems are equal. That means there is no absolute observer. He stated that if you sit in the belly of a ship which is moving on a calm sea, you cannot know or measure its velocity with respect to the ground of the ocean.

Special relativity makes this statement a little different as it introduces the maximum speed $c$, but the principle is the same.

When you are running on the earth, how do you know? I know because I see things moving towards me. Well, I could also argue that all those things are moving towards me. I will also feel my jumping on the street. But needs to be taken away to see what is really going on.

The reference frames have to be inertial reference frames. That means that there must not be any acceleration. If you sit on earth, you have the acceleration by gravity. So this introduces problems.

Imagine the classical example. Two astronauts in empty space float past each other. They only see the other astronaut passing besides them. There is no way of saying that Alice would be fixed and Bob passes her or Alice passes the still standing Bob. The only meaningful thing is the *relative velocity* of the two. Hence *special relativity*.

There is no absolute reference frame for speeds. If you are completely alone, you will always be still standing in your own reference frame. You can define any other reference frame that is moving with respect to you in any direction. You will move into the opposite direction in that frame. Any observer you imagine will observe you at a different speed. That is not a problem, since all those reference frame are equal.